# I cannot stop scrolling error messages after reboot., so I can enter terminal commands

Tags: drivers

In my desktop, I replaced a dying graphics card with a used NVIDIA GT215 GeForce GT240 graphics card. Because the computer began to crash intermittently, I thought the video card might have the wrong driver. So I added the graphics-drivers repository and installed nvidia-driver-535. But I think I was supposed to install nvidia-driver-340. After rebooting, Ubuntu (22.04) keeps repeating a message saying that the "GeForce GT 240 GPU ... is supported through the NVIDIA 340.xx Legacy drivers," that the "535.86.05 driver will ignore this GPU," and that it is "continuing probe." I let it repeat this message for about an hour, then used CTRL-ALT-DEL to reboot. It did the same thing again. How do I stop the scrolling message so I can load the right driver in the terminal?

Comment: I assume you are seeing this in a CLI virtual terminal (VT)? Can you switch to a *different* VT (cycling through Ctrl-Alt-F1 to Ctrl-Alt-F9)?

Comment: I rebooted and tried that already. It goes to a login prompt in a new VT for a moment but returns to the first one before I can type anything. If I manage to get through the login and start typing a command in, it ignores it and keeps repeating the error message mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Stll trying to type commands in other VTs while error messages keep popping up. Will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks. Success. Finally able to log on and complete commands: sudo apt-get remove nvidia-driver-535, sudo apt-get autoremove, sudo apt-get autoclean, reboot.